# Lock on/gravitate to inner divs within larger container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a custom component that will allow you to pick different points which correspond to different values in time. Here is some sample code:

```
<div class="shell">
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <div class="indicator"></div>
  <div class="indicator"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
.shell {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.indicator {
  background-color: #3CB371;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 2px 5px;
  width: 15px;
}

.indicator:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

---

```
var shell = document.querySelector('.shell');

shell.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.path && event.path[0].classList.value === 'indicator') {
    console.log(event);
  }
});
```

This looks like:

[image: Indicators]

I was wondering if it would be possible to write some JS that would allow my mouse to sort of lock into each of these individual circles. Sort of like when you have the grid open in PhotoShop and your mouse will gravitate to the points and lock on.

Ideally, I'd be able to lock on to the center point of each individual circle.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it is possible maybe it's not, the question where your failed attempt ? or did you even try.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the word for that mouse movement is often referred as "snap".

To accomplish that with JavaScript, you would have to be able to manipulate the users mouse position. And as far as I know that is not possible.

Think about the Usability concerns this ability would bring. For example it could bring security issues as the visited page could direct your mouse to a malicious link when you try clicking somewhere else on the page.